# GUI sys tray app on Ubuntu with Clojure

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, ubuntu, clojure

I want to make a GUI application for Ubuntu written in Clojure (so using Java GUI libraries).   I know how to write Swing apps, to run as 'normal' GUI apps.   I want to do something a little different and am not sure how to approach it; I want to write a program to run in the sys tray, and every X minutes remind me something in a small window that shows near the sys tray.

Thanks for the help,
Alex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are targeting java 6 you can use,

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/

works cross platform.

Comment: I actually set this up for one of our apps a couple of days ago - worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at Brian Carpers [clj-qt4-mailtray](https://github.com/briancarper/clj-qt4-mailtray)

It uses Qt so should run cross platform as an added bonus. Brian has an explanatory article [here](http://briancarper.net/blog/398/).